# Landing page with swiper horizontal scrolling and locking normal scroll

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I need to create a desktop (no mobile) landing page similar to this one:

https://chaletbaumatti.ch/history/

but with swiper library.

Swiper has an option to swipe horizontally with a mouse wheel, but:

1. If i scroll slowly through page and mouse hovers over swiper it starts to scroll horizontally before swiper is fully visible
   2 If i scroll too fast i go thorugh swiper section not catching the horizontal scroll

My idea is to use Intersection Observer, enable horizontal scrolling when swiper is fully in viewport and disable if its not - which kind of solves problem 1. Then i tried to lock the page scrolling on same condition, and unlock if swiper reaches end (there is an event for that in swiper).

How can disable page scrolling at this point? I tried multiple solutions:

- disabling wheel event with:

```
document.querySelector('#scrollable').addEventListener('wheel', preventScroll, {passive: false});

function preventScroll(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    return false;
}
```

which works with a huge delay and locks screen in different position

- adding scroll event to jump to same place with:

```
function disableScroll() {
    // Get the current page scroll position
    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,

        // if any scroll is attempted, set this to the previous value
        window.onscroll = function() {
            window.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);
        };
}

function enableScroll() {
    window.onscroll = function() {};
}
```

which causes a little jump on scroll and then setting position back to swiper

- simply disabling overflow-y on body, but this hides page scrollbar and page width 'jumps'.

Any idea how can i solve this one? Or maybe there is a simpler solution